# .htaccess all directories give 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm using .htaccess on my multilingual website to make some URL modifications for nice SEO.

By default all the folders are restricted with 403 Forbidden, but I want to make exceptions on two paths. `/de` and `/en`. Yes, these paths are for multilingual and when I have pages like:

```
www.mywebsite.com/en/page
```

It's working properly, but when I try to return to the main page with link like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/en
```

it shows 403 forbidden.

Here's my full code:

```
RewriteEngine on

#remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#redirect lang
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.*)$ $2.php?lang=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/en
```

On the last line as you can see I've tried to allow access to `/en`, but it doesn't work.

How can I allow the access of these paths: `/en` and `/de` ?

**EDIT:**

After lot of searching, I've found that the main website on the same server that's made on Drupal, it has own .htaccess file and that's why it shows 403 forbidden on the new website (custom cms) that is located on a separate folder inside. But when I delete the .htaccess from the main website as a test, now on the new website when I enter `www.mywebsite.com/en/` it shows 404 not found.

That doesn't happen if I enter 
`www.mywebsite.com/en`

It simply redirects to the index page.

After double check I can see the language switcher on my website automatically change the languages, so if page was `/team`, it acts like `/en/team` and on the front page it acts like this `/en/`, not `/en`.

**EDIT2**

I've followed the w3dk answer, but it still shows the same error.
This is the full code that I'm trying out:

```
RewriteEngine on

#remove .php
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1/index


#redirect lang
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.*)$ $2.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

This line `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1/index` breaks the language switcher functionality. For an example `/de/team` doesn't change to the German content. Right now I've commented that line, 'cos its not working properly.

I'm posting the code from my language switcher too:

```
<?php
$currentURL = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
        <ul class="language-switcher">
            <li><a href="/de/<?php echo $currentURL; ?>">DE</a></li>
            <li><a href="/en/<?php echo $currentURL; ?>">EN</a></li>
        </ul>
```

If I enter this page

```
www.mywebsite.com/en/team
```

and after that click on the language switcher on German version, it successfully shows the German content and the URL is like this:

www.mywebsite.com/de/team

BUT if I go to the front page that has this URL:

```
www.mywebsite.com
```

and click on the language switcher on German version the URL becomes like this and it shows 403 or 404 page:

`www.mywebsite.com/de/`

Comment: I guess in the server setup somewhere. Unfortunately the website is located on shared hosting and I don't have access to the Apache settings.

Comment: Is `/en` a physical directory on the filesystem? A 403 will be the default response if you don't have a `DirectoryIndex` document in that directory.

Comment: No, `/en` is not a physical directory. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: And there is no file `/en.php`? What are you expecting `/en` to load? (ie. what should it be rewritten to?) At the moment it looks like it simply falls through... but why a 403 and not a 404? This isn't something that would be configured in the "server setup" on "shared hosting".

Comment: I want `/en` to load the index page `/en/index`.

Comment: I've just found out why does 403 appears. There's a main website on the server. It's made on Drupal and itself has own .htaccess file. The new website is in a separate folder inside, but I can see that the Drupal's .htaccess controls that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want `/en` to load the index page `/en/index`

Try adding the following *after your first rule*:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1/index
```

This should then be caught again by the final rule that ultimately rewrites the request to `index.php?lang=en`.

Alternatively, try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've tried again with your code and by deleting the Drupal's .htaccess that appears on the main server as a test, but now it shows `404 not found` when I enter `www.mywebsite.com/en/`

Comment: I've updated my answer. Missed off the `/?` at the end of the pattern.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that too, with `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1/index` ...logically, but it still shows 404 not found if I delete the .htaccess from the Drupal's website, otherwise it shows 403 forbidden. It's a real headbanging issue... :) Actually the Drupal .htaccess doesn't make conflicts, it only acts different,  it change 404 pages to 403, nothing more.

Comment: And this new rule is immediately _after_ the first `RewriteRule` and _before_ the second rule block? (Also, remove the trailing `RewriteCond` directive, if you haven't already.)

Comment: I've edited again my main post. Please check it. I've notice when I add the new code from you it breaks the functionality of the language switcher. For an example `/de/team` doesnt change to the German content.

Comment: Does `/en` and `/en/` load the correct content now? From your edits it's unclear what is working and what's not. Your "language switcher" requires a URL of the form `/lang/<something>` - so, yes, that is not going to work for a URL such as `/en` or `/en/` - so that will need to be updated. You could _redirect_ to `/en/index` instead, but I assume you don't want `index` visible in the URL?

Comment: No, `/en/` does not load the content, it shows the error page. `/en` does not load the content too, but no error displayed, it just displays the same front page without functionality to translate. I've didn't find any example of PHP multilingual website with language switcher, so I've just tried with /en/$currentURL. The variable is just the URI with basename and it works great on all other pages, except for the front page. Is there any proper solution? .htaccess is a great tool for creating a good urls but I don't see any examples for this kind of functionality.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to redirect to `/en/index`. I've seen lot of websites that has `www.example.com/en` and it loads the English content, but I don't see any examples how they do that.

Comment: Well, the solution that I found is like this: On index.php I've changed the variable to `$currentURL = 'index';`. So, when I click on the front page, the URL shows `/en/index` or `/de/index`. It's not a best solution, I don't want to display the index in the URL, but at least this works. Thank you very much for your answers. Wish I could find a better way, so to achieve the primary idea: `www.example.com/en`

Comment: After adding the three lines on the bottom, it doesn't break the functionality, but when I enter `www.mywebsite.com/de/`, the same error appears. YES, when I enter `www.mywebsite.com/de`  it change the content to German, that's great. Now still to find a way to change the logic of the language switcher and everything will be great.

Comment: OK, finally, I've made some crazy changes with the switcher and now everything works great. I know that this is lot more easier using some framework, but using Custom CMS is the real challenge.  Thank you again. I'm marking your answer and +1.  :?)